# Veins/Omnett retrieve Traffic Light information

Tags: omnet++, veins, traffic-simulation, sumo

I am new to Veins and omnett and am working on a project that will use traffic lights to map out intersections. http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Traffic_Lights_Value_Retrieval#Command_0xa2:_Get_Traffic_Lights_Variable shows that *ID List* can be retrieved but I am having trouble getting that information. I tried using the command: trafficlight(1).idlists; I included #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h". The error is showing up as "trafficlight was not declared in this scope". I am trying to call this function in BaseWaveAppLayer.cc. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of veins supports traffic light access and control.

Answer (score 0):

The command you mention is implemented in SUMO, but not in Veins 4.4.

You will need to write your own method. For inspiration, you can refer to [similar commands](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L87) and [how they are implemented](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc#L293).